# AddEstablishing an easement in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, parking, easement

How does one establish an easement for parking in the UK? It's an area the size of 5 cars opposite my house where I've regularly parked (not everyday in the week but at least one day per week) over the period of 26 years.

UPDATE: It is on the roadside of privately owned common land, so technically part of a registered common

Comment: Has anyone ever successfully prevented you from parking there?  Is it in plain sight of the street?

Comment: No never. Yes plain to see. It is on the roadside of privately owned common land, so technically part of a registered common.